# How to delay text on TKinter before quit command initiates?

Tags: python, tkinter, adventure

I am using python tkinter for a textbased game, I am curious how would I display the text to show how the user died in the game rather than it automatically killing the game?
I have tried doing 'time.sleep(3)' so that it waits 3 seconds but this seems not to work and the program just kills itself upon hitting a death scenario.

A sample of the code which I am struggling to get it to display:

This part of the code is for when the user decides on what to do, for example if they choose to eliminate the enemy they have a 98% chance of succeeding (just for testing it works, effort dying 1 in 4 times.) But if they die then it should output the text then close the program. In this instance it doesn't? I am thinking it has something to do with the 'quit()'

```
def tunnel_Left(Event=None):
import random
if Command_Line.get().lower() == ("eliminate them"):
    if random.randint(0,100) >= 3:
        update_textbox("""-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Lucky shot, you got them both!
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
It's lucky that there aren't anymore rebels near.
This walkway doesn't offer much cover and rocks are your only weapon now...
There is an inclined part of the path that leads south to higher ground.
There is also a path leading to the west but there could be more rebels that 
way...
West or South?
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n""")
    Command_Line.bind("<Return>", landmine_Choice)
elif random.randint(0,100) < 2:
            update_textbox("""-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
You hit one, but not enough to take him out the fight!
His friend opens fire, you are dead.
GAME OVER...
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n""")
quit()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We can't possibly assume how your game works...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `after` method on [tkinter](/questions/tagged/tkinter) widgets in order to have a delay that doesn't freeze the GUI.

I don't know what `quit` refers to in the OP's example so I'm just gonna create a way using the *non*-MCVE code given above.

Replace:

```
quit()
```

with:

```
assert update_textbox.winfo_class() == 'Text'
update_textbox.after(3000, update_textbox.quit)
```

Now this will make it so that `mainloop` for the GUI will be done for after roughly 3 seconds, *if* the assertion is correct, if not then that's the risk you're taking with an improper example.